# How to add a syntax rule to LaTeX filetype?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, filetype-tex

How can I colorize elements of the regex rule `"\w\+:\w\+:\d\{4\}"` in a LaTeX file ?

If I open a new document with no filetype and add the two following command :

```
syn match Bib3Dots '\w\+:\w\+:\d\{4\}' contains=@NoSpell
hi def link Bib3Dots Comment
```

It get colorized as Comment and there's no spell check as expected.
But it doesn't work in any LaTeX files. Why ?

Thanks